# ListPlot with log scale in x axis

Tags: plotting, histograms

This is the list with the points I will use

```
points = {{1, 1.34795, 0.054925}, {1.34795, 1.81697, 0.0469403}, 
{1.81697, 2.45792, 0.044499}, {2.45792, 3.32495, 0.0447266},
{3.32495, 4.48188, 0.0460946}, {4.48188, 6.08446, 0.04784},
{6.08446, 8.17245, 0.0495524}, {8.17245, 11.0161, 0.051065}, 
{11.0161, 14.9551, 0.0523605}, {14.9551, 20.1587, 0.0534072}, {20.1587, 30, 0.05435}}
```

each element of this list {a,b,c} contains

- a = left point of the bin
- b = right point of the bin
- c = height of the bar

Then, I create the following histogram

```
ListPlot[points[[All, {2, 3}]], Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> None, 
Prolog -> {Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{#[[1]], 0}, 
{#[[2]], #[[3]]}] & /@ points}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: img]

How to set the Log scale on the x-axis? I tried with ListLogLinearPlot

```
ListLogLinearPlot[points[[All, {2, 3}]], Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> None, 
Prolog -> {Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{#[[1]], 0}, 
{#[[2]], #[[3]]}] & /@ points}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

but it returns a wrong result

[image: img2]

Comment: What exactly is wrong? The x-axis is in log scale

Comment: I think it is a bug.  I can reproduce the issue with version 11.0.1 in Win 7 Pro.  The same happens for `ListPlot` with the `ScalingFunctions` option.

Comment: @Felix Notice that the first 4 bars are missing and that the bar heights are decreasing when they should be increasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually `Log` the coordinates for the `Rectagle`:

```
Show[ListLogLinearPlot[points[[All, {2, 3}]], Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> None, 
  Prolog -> {Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[Black], 
    Rectangle[{Log[#[[1]]], 0}, {Log[#[[2]]], #[[3]]}] & /@ points}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{.5, 40}, {0, 0.06}}], 
 ListLogLinearPlot[points[[All, {2, 3}]]]]
```

[image]